# How do I sum up records within Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods, model, sum

I have an ItemsSold model which has the total number of magazines, books, videos, greeting_cards, pens sold for a single day. How do I elegantly return an array with the weekly sold totals for each item for the last arbitrary number of weeks?

I have a model file:

```
#items_sold.rb
class ItemsSold < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :magazines, :books, :videos, :greeting_cards, :pens, :sold_date

end
```

My table is defined as follows:

```
t.integer :magazines
t.integer :books
t.integer :videos
t.integer :greeting_cards
t.integer :pens
t.datetime :sold_date
```

Also, is it possible to return monthly totals for the last year, too?

Answer (score 0):

See [ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000296)

```
by_week = (1...10).inject({}) do |wh, weeks_ago|
  startat = weeks_ago.weeks.ago
  endat = (weeks_ago - 1).weeks.ago
  wh[weeks_ago] = [:magazines, :books, :videos, :greeting_cards, :pens].inject({}) do |sh, attr|
    sh[attr] = ItemsSold.where("sold_date > ? and sold_date <= ?", startat, endat).sum(attr.to_s)
    sh
  end
  wh
end
```

That will return a hash like `{1 => {:magazines => 5, :books => 33, ...}, 2 => {{:magazines => 13, :books => 28, ...}}, ...}`, where each key is a week number (1 for this past week, 2 for two weeks ago, etc..) and the value is another hash with the sums.

Comment: Great thanks, is it possible to also get totals for each week, and then put each week as a hash with in array? I think your example gives the totals for the last 5 weeks, rather than breaking it down by week.

Comment: @GeekActive, of course you can. Just adjust the conditions on the ItemSold sum. I updated the above example to show you how it might work. I don't know exactly the data structure you are looking for, but you get the idea right? Just use loops to determine how you want to segment the data based on dates, and then use `ItemsSold.sum(attr, date_conditions)` to get the sums.

Comment: @GeekActive, alternatively, in fewer queries, you can get the week number for a date using a mysql function, and group by that. But that is a lot more complicated than using ruby to do the work for you, and should not be necessary unless you discover the ruby is slow because of massive data sets need to optimize on queries.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was stuck on the :conditions part, will try it out!

Comment: @Ben, I originally took a look at "Active Record Queries" in Railscasts, http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3... but couldn't figure out how to get sums that way using that method. :-(

Comment: @GeekActive, I've updated the query to be more Rails-3-friendly. Instead of the old finder :conditions hash, it now uses a where() method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just curious what does "wh" and "sh" stand for in the code? Still wrapping my head around injects, too.

Comment: "week hash" and "sum hash". The injects aren't necessary here -- you could do that same things with maps and other loops, but i figured inject was just that simplest way to do this.