# Ruby: summing up values within an array of hashes between certain dates

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes in Ruby:

```
array = [
  {:date => Wed, 04 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 200}
  {:date => Wed, 04 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 100}
  {:date => Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 300}
  {:date => Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 150}
]
```

I'd like to be able to combine the values within each day so that I have a new array like this:

```
array = [
  {:date => Wed, 04 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 300}
  {:date => Tue, 03 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 450}
]
```

What's the most elegant way to search the array by day and sum up the values for each day?

This is what I initially tried:

```
entries = [
  {:date => Wed, 04 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 200}
  {:date => Wed, 04 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 100}
  {:date => Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 300}
  {:date => Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00,
   :value => 150}
]

first_day = 29.days.ago.beginning_of_day
total_days = 30

day_totals = (0...total_days).inject([]) do |array, num|
    startat = first_day + num.day
    endat = startat.end_of_day

    total_value_in_day = entries.where("date >= ? and date <= ?", startat, endat).sum(:value)

    array << {:date => startat, :value => total_value_in_day}
end
```

I realized my mistake was with the `where` method which is a Rails method for searching objects, and can't be used on arrays. So my main question, is there a way to search arrays or hashes with conditions.

Comment: The most elegant way really is for you to [write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158947/how-do-i-sum-up-records-within-rails-3) [some code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382543/how-do-i-add-values-from-two-different-arrays-of-hashes-together) yourself, if you don't mind my being _elegantly_ blunt. Elegance in code is a value, and it is good to reach for it, but you cannot reach mastery without (painful) exercise. Perhaps [read a good book](http://programmingzen.com/ruby-and-rails-recommended-books/)

Comment: edited the post to show the code I tried on my own, and where I was stuck.

Comment: Where does the combined value 450 for Tue 03 May come from?

Comment: Aha, much better question now !

Comment: @sawa, oops that was a typo, just fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the entries to create a new array:

```
totals = Hash.new(0)
array.each do |entry|
  totals[entry[:date]] += entry[:value]
end

# Now totals will be something like this:
# => {"Wed, 04 May 2011" => 300, "Tue, 03 May 2011" => 450...}

# If you then want this in the same array format you started with:
new_array = totals.collect{ |key, value| {:date => key, :value => value} }
# => [{:date => "Wed, 04 May 2011", :value => 300}, {....}]
```

Comment: This worked great! I also had to use `entry[:date].beginning_of_day` to add up entries within varying times of the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For 1.9.2:

```
>> array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |el, hash| hash[el[:date]] += el[:value] } 
#=> {"Wed, 04 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>200, "Wed, 04 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>100, "Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>450}
```

Also works with 1.8:

```
>> array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, el| hash[el[:date]] += el[:value] ; hash } 
#=> {"Wed, 04 May 2011 00:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>200, "Wed, 04 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>100, "Tue, 03 May 2011 01:00:00 PDT -07:00"=>450}
```